# how to test defineModel use vitest?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vitest

How to test `defineModel` with `vitest`？

I've write a `Toast.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="show">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
interface ToastType {
  text: string
  time?: number
}

const props = defineProps<ToastType>()

const show = defineModel({default: false })

watch(show, () => {
  if (show.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      show.value = false
    }, props.time || 2000)
  }
})
</script>
```

and test file:

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi, afterEach, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import Toast from '../Toast.vue'

const props = {
  text: 'hello toast',
  time: 2500,
  modelValue: false
}

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.useFakeTimers()
})

afterEach(() => {
  vi.useRealTimers()
})

vi.useFakeTimers()

describe('Toast.vue', () => {
  it('Toast Props', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Toast, {
      propsData: props
    })

    await wrapper.setProps({
      modelValue: true
    })

    vi.runAllTimers()

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('update:modelValue')
    expect(wrapper.emitted('update:modelValue')).toHaveLength(1)
   
    // error AssertionError: expected true to be false // Object.is equality
    expect(wrapper.vm.modelValue).toBe(false)
  })
})
```

I really do not know how to do, please know the small partners to guide, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For **vue:"^3.4"** changing the model value directly seems to work:

```js
// inside CheckboxLikeComponent
const model = defineModel<boolean>({
    required: true,
    set: (value) => {
        state.touched = true;
        return value;
    },
});
```

```js
type TFoo = {
    comp: ReturnType<
        typeof withComponent<
            typeof CheckboxLikeComponent,
            ICheckboxLikeComponentState,
            {
                model: boolean;
            }
        >
    >;
};


beforeEach<TFoo>((context) => {
      context.comp= withComponent(CheckboxLikeComponent, {
          props: {
              name: 'test',
              modelValue: false,
          },
      });
});

    

it<TFoo>('element is updated by changing the v-model', async ({
    comp,
}) => {
    const checkboxElement = comp.wrapper.find('input').element;

    expect(checkboxElement.checked).toBeFalsy();

    comp.wrapper.vm.model = true;

    await nextTick();

    expect(checkboxElement.checked).toBeTruthy();
    expect(comp.state.value?.touched).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is expected. Even if you remove the last line, your test is still complete.

If you declare a two-way binding prop using the `defineModel` macro, like so:

```js
const show = defineModel<boolean>({default: false})
```

mutating the value, for example:

```js
show.value = false
```

is essentially translated to:

```js
$emit('update:modelValue', false)
```